# Installing pure-ftpd in docker (Debian wheezy), error 421

Tags: ftp, debian, docker, pureftpd

i'm trying to setup a simple container i docker with pure-ftpd running.

But on running `service pure-ftpd start` i get this error:

```
Starting ftp server: Running: /usr/sbin/pure-ftpd -l pam -E -8 UTF-8 -O clf:/var/log/pure-ftpd/transfer.log -u 1000 -B
421 Unable to switch capabilities : Operation not permitted
```

Here's the Dockerfile for testing this:

```
FROM debian:wheezy

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y pure-ftpd-common pure-ftpd

CMD service pure-ftpd start && \
    /bin/bash

EXPOSE 21/tcp
```

In this test i'm using debian wheezy, but i've tried with ubuntu too and i get exact the same error.

---

*[ Edit ]*

Working version with this fix is now available here: https://index.docker.io/u/stilliard/pure-ftpd/

Comment: Why was this down voted after it was closed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems your host machine does not allow capability switching.

You could modify the `optflags` in the source package for `pure-ftpd` by adding `--without-capabilities`

Steps to add in your Docker file

- apt-get source pure-ftpd
- in the `rules` file, append with sed the `--without-capabilities` options
- use `dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc` to build the package and install it with `dpkg -i`

This should do the trick.

Comment: Excellent thanks, i'm going to update my question in a bit with my new Dockerfile in case anyone else finds this issue. Thanks again!

Comment: > in the rules file, append with sed the --without-capabilities options

Where exactly?